# Как в одном ряду таблицы активировать не более 5 ячеек?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите как решить данную задачу: "Сделайте так, чтобы в одном ряду таблице можно было активировать не более 5 ячеек."

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.table tr');

for (let row of rows) {
  row.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    let items = document.querySelectorAll('td.green');

    if (items.length < 5) {
      event.target.classList.add('green');
    }
  })
}
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Вот моя попытка решить задачу, но в данном случае работает на 5 активных ячеек по всей таблице, а не в каждом отдельном ряду.

Я никак не могу понять, как зацепится к определенному ряду.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
const table = document.querySelector('.table');
table.addEventListener('click',({target}) => {
  if (target.tagName == 'TD') {  
    let len = target.closest('tr').querySelectorAll('td.green').length;    
    if (len >= 5) {
      target.classList.remove('green');
      return;
    }    
    target.classList.toggle('green');
  }
})
```

```css
td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам, в слушателе клика, просто надо было искать не в `document`-е, а в самих строчках `row`. От себя добавил возможность убирать выделение, если элементов больше пяти, а то после выбора 5-ти ячеек менять ничего нельзя было

```js
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('.table tr');

for (const row of rows) {
  row.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const items = row.querySelectorAll('td.green');

    event.target.classList.toggle('green', items.length < 5);
  })
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #777;
}

td {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text1</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text2</td>
    <td>text1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
    <td>text3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: снять выделение можно только с 5-ой активной?

Comment: @PavelNazarian Ага

Comment: @EzioMercer [а такое поведение](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RuF7v.png) ожидалось? (Я просто быстро и случайно нажимал на текст, сначала в одном ряду, потом переходил на другой)

Comment: @ΝNL993 Я не тестировал. Но раз это есть, то это не баг, а фича :)

Comment: 0


@PavelNazarian, самое обидное, что я так и думал, что нужно просто обратится к row, но походу где то делал ошибку и почему то у меня не выходило. Спасибо, теперь попробовал переписать и все вышло)

Comment: @MaXiMuS Вы либо ответом ошились либо с обращением :) Но рад, что у вас всё получилось)